# node/express res.redirect block by cors policy; Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: node.js, express, cors, preflight

I have react/express app that has a payment section. which in the express server it must connect to the bank api.
[the payRouter.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR23g.png)
after a post request to the request api of the payment gateway, we get a reponse that if it is valid, we must **redirect** the user to the online payment page of the bank. here is the problem, and the cors error occurs even though **I have used**  `app.use(cors());` in the main server.js file. [the server.js file of node/express server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5NCP.png)

the error says:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. ( picture below )
> [the cors error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRsKT.png)

the vague part to me is when I'm trying to kinda bypass the cors and instead of redirecting the user from node/express api, sending a response to the client having the link the express server got from the bank api, and **make user click on the link** in the browser, **no such error will be thrown**.

the app has been deployed to the vps server and works totally ok on the server except the redirecting to the payment page ( it's not localhost ).

It has been several days I have been struggling, I'd be really appreciate if youn help me out.

Answer (score -2):

Try this middleware on top of your routes...

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  next();
});
```

Hope this works for you...

Comment: Simply add this on above where you declared your routes in server.js or app.js

Comment: thanks for replying, but still getting the same error.  @smitgajera

Comment: Your error replicating Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing right so we add this in our request please confirm this via inspect -> networks -> your request call -> headers